# Download images with the same name in XML

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

I'm trying to download product images or get file paths in XML. I'm having trouble with the same name. Thank you.

XML Files

```
-<products>
-<product>
<product_code>AXX-655</product_code>
<product_name>Samsung Led TV</product_name>
-<Images>
<Image>https://max.cloud/37233/products-77d4.jpg</Image>
<Image>https://max.cloud/37233/products-254789.jpg</Image>
<Image>https://max.cloud/37233/products-f010.jpg</Image>
<Image>https://max.cloud/37233/products-8004.jpg</Image>
</Images>
-</product>
-<product>
<product_code>ACH-645</product_code>
<product_name>LG Led TV</product_name>
-<Images>
<Image>https://max.cloud/37233/products-895777.jpg</Image>
<Image>https://max.cloud/37233/products-3652.jpg</Image>
<Image>https://max.cloud/37233/products-k0120.jpg</Image>
</Images>
-</product>
-</products>
```

I am trying to download product images by product id or product name
PHP Files

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmllocalurl) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach ($xml->children() ->children() as $child) {
    $name = $child->product_name;
    $url = $child->Images->Image;
    $img = 'imgfiles/'.$name.'.jpg';
    $url = $child->product_name;
    file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```

Comment: Can you [edit] to explain the problem more clearly? What is the _expected_ output / result, and what is the _current_ output / result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are dealing with xml, you are probably better off using xpath to extract what I believe is your target data.

The below just presents the data; you can then save it as you see fit:

```
$items = $xml->xpath('//product');
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $name = $item->xpath('./product_name')[0];
    $code = $item->xpath('./product_code')[0];
    $images = $item->xpath('.//Image/text()');
    echo $name," " ,$code," " ;
    foreach ($images as $image) {
      echo $image , " ";
    }
    echo "\r\n";
};
```

output (based on your sample xml):

```
Samsung Led TV AXX-655 https://max.cloud/37233/products-77d4.jpg https://max.cloud/37233/products-254789.jpg https://max.cloud/37233/products-f010.jpg https://max.cloud/37233/products-8004.jpg 
LG Led TV ACH-645 https://max.cloud/37233/products-895777.jpg https://max.cloud/37233/products-3652.jpg https://max.cloud/37233/products-k0120.jpg
```

Comment: @Designer015 Not sure why they closed your question, but glad it worked for you. Also, don't forget to accept the answer, please.

Comment: Since I am a new member, I do not know how to use the site fully. Where should I accept?

Comment: @Designer015 It's ok, we were all there once! "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in."